# libgdx-freetype how to scale font wth correct letter spacing?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, freetype

With the previous version of FreeType there was a method setScale() Now I can change the scale with:

```
bitmapFont.getData().SetScale();
```

but I' ve this issue with te letter spacing:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/35PGQ.png

I can't play with the size parameter because I've a  small viewPort and i can't change it.

Comment: problem is not with `free-type`, it's with `BitmapFont`, [Changes](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3658) from 1.5.6 version, you can check, how libgdx render bitmapfont now

Comment: ok I know, but how can I obtain the same result like SetScale in the previous version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll recommend not to scale `BitmapFont`. May be your bitmapfont rendering result is due to high scale down of your `BitmapFont` that you generated by [free-type Font](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype) generator.

You can use `bitmapFont.getData().setScale(float x, float y);` but scaling should be reasonable extent, not two much high or low.

You can create `BitmapFont` with `FreeTypeFontGenerator` with your required size so that you don't need to scale up/down.

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/timesBold.ttf"));
FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
```

Change font size in parameter and initialize BitmapFont:

```
fontParameter.size = 25; // by default this value is 16
BitmapFont font = fontGenerator.generateFont(fontParameter);
```

---

Want to use `font.setScale();` instead of `font.getData().setScale()`, reactoring are from Version 1.5.6 so you need to use older version from this version. I've a link of [1.5.5 version](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/releases/libgdx-1.5.5.zip), download it. Zip having `gdx-setup.jar` file, create project from that `.jar`, import project into your IDE and run.

Comment: I have FreeTypeFontGenerator with size = 400 and i use setscale() so i can't resize it, I can't use only the size because I have to change the viewport and I can't do this. I try to use the old lib but there's something wrong and the app crash, but I don't understand: from this version and the old 1.5.5 there is only some refactoring? why in the previous version everything goes fine and in this version there'are a problem?

Comment: Today I tested `free-type` and `BitmapFont` from  version `1.5.5 `, it's working fine as expected.